# Model a fountain

Tags: fluid-dynamics, bernoulli-equation

I try to calculate the shape of a fountain under the assumptions of an invscid, incompressible fluid, so Bernoulli is applicable.

So the task is to get the evolving shape of a cylindrical waterflow leaving a pipe at constant velocity $\mathbf{v}=v_0 \mathbf{e}_z$ with cross section $A_0$ into z direction (so raising vertically from the ground, e.g. starting at $z=0$).

Bernoulli gives me (assuming no angular dependence):

\begin{equation}
v_r(r,z)^2+v_z(r,z)^2+2gz=v_0^2\tag{1}
\end{equation}

z is the height of the fountain. Continuity equation:

\begin{equation}
r(z)^2=\frac{v_z}{v_0}r_0^2\tag{2}
\end{equation}

$r$ is the Radius of the fountain at height $z$. 
So now I have 2 equations and 3 unkowns: $v_r$, $v_z$ and $r(z)$.

That's as far as I get. Questions:

- Is (2) correct? I get this from using the divergence theorem of the continuity equation but this might be wrong..
- I need a third equation to solve the system which one is it?

edit:

To be clear: $v_r$ shall not be ignored

Answer (score 2):

Sure, (2) is correct, even though I have no idea what "Gauß integration" might be, and why you would need it. Whether or not you have all the equations you need really depends on the level of approximation you are supposed to use. At the undergraduate level, you would ignore $v_r$, and you'd be done.

If you are expected to produce a potential flow solution of this problem then things get a lot more interesting. In that case the JFM paper by Tuck, *[The Shape of Free Jets of Water under Gravity](https://www-cambridge-org.ezproxy.lib.purdue.edu/core/journals/journal-of-fluid-mechanics/article/div-classtitlethe-shape-of-free-jets-of-water-under-gravitydiv/952B99F9999454DA205956152855400B)* should provide some inspiration. Notice also that for the general potential flow case, you cannot assume uniform pressure throughout the jet, so your equation (1) is incomplete.

Comment: Sorry "Gauß integration" is the german phrase -I mean the divergence theorem.
$v_r$ shall not be ignored.

Comment: What's your background, and what are the tools and equations at your disposal? Like I said, if you are not allowed to neglect the radial velocity, the problem becomes *a lot* harder. See the edit of my original answer.

Comment: My tools are Navier Stokes and Continuity equation ;)
Thanks for the link to the paper I will have a look at it

Comment: You don't need the Navier-Stokes equations (in which case your only hope would be a numerical solution of the full set of PDEs), since you assume incompressible inviscid flow. With that, your equations decouple into a Laplace equation for the velocity potential, plus the Bernoulli equation. Have fun!

Comment: If I use Bernoulli then I am already using NS (or euler to be more precise).. Sorry which equations decouple into a Laplace eq?

Comment: No, the Bernoulli equation is not valid for the general Navier-Stokes case. For potential flow the set of the momentum (Navier-Stokes) and continuity equations decouples into a Laplace equation for the kinematics of the velocity field, plus the Bernoulli equation embodying its dynamics.